# Callback not being called for passport-amazon

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a `passport-amazon` strategy on a route in an express server (I have stripped out the user handling code from the callback for brevity):

passport is initialized thusly in server.js:

```
//configure passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./config/passport')(passport);
```

The passport strategy is added in `require('./config/passport')(passport)`:

```
passport.use(
  new AmazonStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.AMAZON_CLIENT_ID,
              clientSecret: process.env.AMAZON_CLIENT_SECRET,
              callbackURL: process.env.AMAZON_CALLBACK_URL
          },
     (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
       console.log('in the callback for amazon auth');
       //user handling code here
       return done(null, user);
```

);

the route:

```
routes.get(
        '/login',
        passport.authenticate(
            'amazon',
            {
                scope: ['profile']
            }
        ),
        (req, res) => {
          console.log('something happens here');
        }
      )
```

The authentication makes it to Amazon and the callback URL is used. The middleware I have on the route for the callback url:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated())
            return next();

        res.redirect('/');
}
```

is being called and `req.isAuthenticated()` is `false`. The passport callback function never logs to the console.

Comment: You have not return back the user using `done` in amazon passport middleware

Comment: I removed that section of the code for tidiness in the example. The problem is that the function is never even called. That log statement is never executed.

Comment: The only thing comes to my mind is that you didn't initialize the passport

Comment: I added the passport initialization to the question.

Comment: I added process.nextTick(() => {}) with the console message and I still get nothing.

Comment: Which route you use to show login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem using the [example code](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-amazon/blob/master/examples/login/app.js). I needed another authenticate call on the intermediate callback route:

```
routes.get(
      '/amazon/auth/callback', 
      passport.authenticate('amazon', {failureRedirect: '/'}),    
      (req, res) => {
        console.log("at /amazon/auth/callback");
        res.redirect('/highlights');
    });
```

This executes the passport callback and the isLoggedIn method passes.

Thanks to Ebrahim Pasbani for his help and sticking in there with me.

Answer (score 1):

Your `isLoggedIn` middleware is the bug. You shouldn't check for auth in callback url, because at that point there is no `user` yet.

You can redirect user to a secure route in callback route and use `isLoggedIn` middleware on that route.

Comment: I added an intermediate route with no middleware check and redirecetd to the middleware protected route. Same problem, the passport strategy callback is never logging to the console.

Comment: @Lunchbox Does your amazon callback have `isLoggedIn` middleware yet?

Comment: @Lunchbox Oh I see you solved your problem now. Cool